# Is it possible to replace default PHP function?

Tags: php, function

php has function `var_dump` as default i want to replace `var_dump` function  from PHP with my own var_dump

is it possible to do that ?

Comment: you mean override that function? like this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to `rename_function` and then `override_function`:

```
rename_function('var_dump', 'php_var_dump');
override_function('var_dump', '$expression', 'return print_r($expression, true);');
```

which does not necessarily mean, that this would make sense.

better add a [logging library](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/php-logging-libraries/).